# Getting "You can not convert from 'int?' to 'int'" when using Linq's Contains method on a list of Int32

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, lambda

The problem is that I have a list of Int32 and I need to see if elements of another list are in the first list.

Here's my actual code:

```
var b = ML_Contratos.Where(m => m.Borrado == false && m.Idproyecto == 492)
                    .Select(m=> m.Idcontrato)
                    .ToList();

var lista = ML_AdyDeds.Where(a => b.Contains(a.Idcontrato) && a.Autorizado == false)
                      .Select(a => a.Idcontrato)
                      .ToList();
```

The error that im having is:

> "You can not convert from 'int?' to 'int'"

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well which is `int?` and which is `int`? We can't see any of the types involved, making it harder to help you.

Comment: The error is that you are getting a `null` value somewhere and assigning it  to an int

Comment: What is the type of `Idcontrato`?

Comment: b is a list of Int32 and a.Idcontrato is an Int32? thats why i get that error

Comment: Where(m => m.Borrado == false && m.Idproyecto.HasValue && m.Idproyecto.Value == 492)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to casting your nullable ints to ints, you could call `.Cast<int?>()` on your collection of ints to convert them to nullable ints.